# Setting monthly usage limit - Django API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am going through Django rest framework documentation and other questions here trying to figure if there is a way to customize it for monthly rate limit by user-group.

logic:
User A - Group 1
User B - Group 2

Group 1 - allowed 10 calls per month to endpoint
Group 2 - allowed 100 calls per montg

any help is much appreciated, I am new to Django and fascinated by DRF

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have so low limits, you can log each request in separate model and check limits manually.

```
class RareEndpointRequest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    endpoint = models.TextField("Endpoint's URL")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


def some_endpoint(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user

    request_count = RareEndpointRequest.objects.filter(
        user=user,
        endpoint='some_endpoint',
        created_at__year=timezone.now().year,
        created_at__month=timezone.now().month,
    ).count()

    if request_count > request_limit_by_group(user.group):
        return HttpResponse("Rate limit", status=429)

    # do your actions

    RareEndpointRequest.objects.create(user=user, endpoint='some_endpoint')

    return HttpResponse("Some data")
```